# Home network setup - must everything be on the same subnet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I'm having some trouble setting up my home network...

It consists of the following components

Home Network:

[image]

- PC and HP Microserver (both with gigabit connections)
- Netgear DGN2200 ADSL modem
- Xiaomi WiFi router mini (running OpenWRT - not gigabit ethernet)
- 5 port gigabit switch

The adsl modem defaults to `192.168.0.1`, while the Mi WiFi defaults to `10.0.0.1`.
Both have DHCP servers...

What is the optimal way to set this up?

I initially had the PC, file server, and wireless devices on the `10.0.0.*` subnet, 
with the mini router using `192.168.0.1` as the default gateway but this is no longer working...I can't ping `192.168.0.1` from my pc (which was assigned `10.0.0.25`).

Should I have the ADSL modem and mini router on the same subnet (`10.0.0.*` or `192.168.0.*`)? If so, must I disable DHCP on the ADSL modem?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to disable routing and DHCP in the Wi-Fi router - set it to bridge mode.

Comment: It looks like your modem is also a router and a WiFi hot spot. I'd just use that. If you want to extend your network so that the Wifi reaches further you can use that other modem but if you do that you should just set it up as a bridge and give it a 192.168.0.* IP address. Just put everything on that subnet.

Comment: @krowe the wireless on the modem only supports 802.11N - which is why I got the other wireless router

Comment: @RonMaupin I'll try this and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got this to work fine with different subnets -

The modem is set to its default `192.168.0.1` with DHCP set to `192.168.0.2`.

The router is set to its default `10.0.0.1` with DHCP set to range `10.0.0.100-250`.

All devices that are connected to the network are assigned to the `10.0.0` subnet.

I must have changed a setting on the router that caused it to stop working...